# Pagos con dinero disponible en la billetera de MercadoPago

Tags: php, android, mercadopago

Buenas tardes comunidad!!

Soy nuevo en el mundo de MercadoPago y estoy detenido en un inconveniente, espero ser claro y lograr explicarme.

Genero una preferencia de pago en MP a traves del SDK para PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
MercadoPago\SDK::configure(['ACCESS_TOKEN' => "");

$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = "Descripción";
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->currency_id = "ARS";
$item->unit_price = 100;

$payer = new MercadoPago\Payer();
$payer->email = $datos['email'];
$payer->identification = array("type" => "DNI","number" => 11222333);

$preference->payment_methods = array("installments" => 6);

$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->payer = $payer;
$preference->save();
```

La preferencia se crea correctamente. Luego la utilizo en una app para android pero el inconveniente es que no me aparece la opción de transferencia de dinero disponible en la billetera del usuario (account_money).

Por ahora todas las pruebas las estoy realizando con el token de prueba, no estoy seguro si eso tendrá algo que ver.

Espero me puedan dar una mano con este tema.

Muchisimas gracias. Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 0):

El usuario de prueba que utilizas posee un monto asignado en su cartera como para poder disponer del mismo para un pago??   Ya que si por defecto el sistema no detecta dinero no muestra la opcion de abonar con dicho medio y lo saltea

Comment: Realmente no estoy seguro de si la billetera del usuario de prueba tiene dienero disponible

Comment: me comentaron que para que te aparezca la opción de la billetera del usuario tengo que excluir los demás métodos de pago quedaría algo así: 

`$preference->payment_methods = array(
"excluded_payment_types" => array(
array("id" => "credit_card"),
array("id" => "debit_card"),
array("id" => "prepaid_card")
),
 "installments" => 6
);`